# AngularJS using $http with optional data field

Tags: angularjs

I have the following function which I use to post data to an API endpoint. Problem I am having now is that the $http data field is optionally sent based on the function postdate param. When I try running this code I get an error.

```
  Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (
```

Can someone please help me by telling me what I am doing wrong and how to fix this problem? Thanks

```
    postClient: function(postdata, dataobj, Token){

          var Deferred = $q.defer();
          $http({ method: 'POST',
                  url: 'http://api.domain.com/private/clients',

                  if(postdate =='1'){
                     data: dataobj,
                  }

                  headers: { 'Token' : Token }
          }).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
                Deferred.resolve(data);
          }).error(function(data,status,headers,config){ 
                Deferred.reject(status);                  
          });

         return Deferred.promise;    
     }
```

Comment: That's not even close to being valid Javascript. You've put an if-block in the middle of an object declaration.

Comment: @ivarni I could see this being an obvious point of newbie confusion and thus a valid question

Comment: @DougT. I just dont see how this question would ever solve anything for anyone else than the OP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to skip the `data: dataObject` line, the you could `angular.extend()` to extend the `config` object, so if `data` object is empty then the resultant object .i.e. `config` stays the same

```
var Deferred = $q.defer(),
    data = {},
    config = {
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://api.domain.com/private/clients',
        headers: {
            'Token': Token
        }
    }

if (postdate === '1') {
    data = dataObj;
}

$http(angular.extend(config, data));
```

Comment: This is wrong assumption from your line '.i.e. config stays the same'.As per Angular documentation " the Extend method,  Extends the destination object `dst` by copying all of the properties from the `src` object(s)
 * to `dst`. You can specify multiple `src` objects."

Answer (score 2):

You have placed an `if` statement within an object literal. When you start typing:

```
{ method: 'POST',
  ...
}
```

you're specifying an object. Legal syntax says that values can be identifiers (what you have) or strings. Values can be legal Javascript values, such as other numbers, strings, other javascript objects, and functions. (In this case, as you're posting something to be converted to JSON, you can't have functions).

Its a little hard to discern what you intend. Do you mean to post an empty object if postdate === '1'? Or do you mean to post an empty string perhaps?

Here's an example of how to do it with an empty object. I've moved the if statement out to the function body, not the object literal and saved it in a variable:

```
      var Deferred = $q.defer();
      var data = {};
      if (postdate === '1') {
          data = dataObj;
      }
      $http({ method: 'POST',
              url: 'http://api.domain.com/private/clients',
              data: data,
              headers: { 'Token' : Token }

      ...
```

Comment: My intention was to exclude data:dataobj, line completely if postdate === '1'. Your approach is perfect but I was wondering if there is a way not to send data:dataobj instead of sending it with an empty object in case dataobj value is not 1? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var Deferred = $q.defer();
  var data = {};
  if (postdate == '1') {
      data = dataObj;

   $http({ method: 'POST',
              url: 'http://api.domain.com/private/clients',
              data: data,
              headers: { 'Token' : Token }
          ...
      }

else{
      alert('We will not send any empty object...');
}
```